# RegularExpressionValidator in ASP.Net for checking file extension in FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, file-upload

I am using a RegularExpressionValidator to make sure on client-side that the file extension uploaded through ASP.Net file upload controls is '.txt' and not anything else.

But even when I upload a .txt file, the validator still displays the error message.

My code is as below. **What is wrong with the RegularExpressionValidator that is causing it to error even with txt files?**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" CssClass="formfield" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
 runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Only Files with txt extensions are allowed!"
 ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))
 +(.txt)$" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" SetFocusOnError="true" 
 Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Have you verified your regex works correctly?  I suggest testing it with a .txt file name to make sure it's running right.  I typically use http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Garrison-  I found the answer as I have explained in my new post under this. I should have had the entire Regex expression in same line in aspx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in my html for RegularExpressionValidator.

I had the value for ***ValidationExpression*** ***split across two lines*** in the aspx file. As soon as I put the complete expression in a single line in aspx file, it started to work as expected.

**So it seems the lesson is to never split a regular expression across multiple lines** when using RegularExpressionValidator in ASP.Net.

Comment: Good find!  I would suggest never splitting anything contained within quotes onto multiple lines in ASPX markup.  You'll run into a lot of unintended consequences if you do that often.